# Payara Server doesn't start, The Master Password is required to start the server

Tags: payara

Hello to the whole community. I have a problem with my payara 5.2020 application server. When i want to start it with the command systemctl start payara.service, it doesn't start and show me this error message :

The Master Password is required to start the server.  No console, no prompting possible.  You should either create the domain
java[3370]: Command start-domain failed.

```
-- The result is failed. 
systemd[1]: Unit payara.service entered failed state. 
systemd[1]: payara.service failed.              
systemd[1]: payara.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for payara.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start Payara Server v5.201.
-- Subject: Unit payara.service has failed
```

I tried to change de default password of my domain but it still doesn't work.

Thank to you All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not confuse the admin password and the master password. The admin password is used to access Admin Console and run management asadmin commands that change the domain configuration. The master password is used to decrypt sensitive information stored in the domain configuration and can either be saved on disk or needs to be specified when the server is started.

From your error message I assume that the master password is not saved on disk. You can either save it if you set a new master password with the `--savemasterpassword`:

```
asadmin change-master-password --savemasterpassword
```

Or, if you know the master password (if you didn't change it, the default password is always *changeit*), then you need to modify your start-domain command that's executed by the service script to specify the password in a password file, e.g.:

```
asadmin --passwordfile passwords.txt start-domain
```

With the master password specified in a separate `passwords.txt` file like this:

```
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=mypassword
```

Look here for more info how to specify passwords non-interactively (the service can't ask for passwords interactively): https://ondro.inginea.eu/index.php/configure-passwords-in-payara-server-and-glassfish/